# How To Fix Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File when using React, Firebase and Filepond

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, filepond

I'm trying to upload a users avatar when creting a firebase user, After creating a user here

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password)
    .then(credential=>{
     const photoUrl = this.handleUpload(credential)
})
```

I create a handle upload function which returns a photoUrl below

```
handleUpload=(credential)=>{
    const {avatar} = this.state;
    const upload = storage.ref(`avatars/${credential.user.uid}`).put(avatar)
    upload.on('state_changed',(snapshot)=>{
      let progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    },(e)=>{
      console.log(e)
    },()=>{
      return storage.ref("avatars").child(`${credential.user.uid}`).getDownloadURL()
    })
  }
```

and the filepond UI instance is declared in the UI as follows

```
const { ....,avatar,....} = this.state;

<FilePond 
  ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
  files={avatar}
  fileValidateTypeLabelExpectedTypes="Invalid File Type"
  imagePreviewMaxFileSize='3MB'
  imageValidateSizeMinWidth="400"
  imageValidateSizeMaxWidth="1024"            
  imageValidateSizeMinHeight="400"
  imageValidateSizeMaxHeight="1024"
  imagePreviewTransparencyIndicator="green"
  maxFileSize='3MB'
  labelIdle={'Drag & Drop your Profile Picture or <span class="filepond--label-action"> Browse </span>'}
  acceptedFileTypes={['image/png', 'image/jpeg']}
  onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
    this.setState({
      avatar: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
    });
  }}              
/>
```

But I get the expected blob or file error...
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to log what the `avatar` value contains before it's sent to storage. Your storage is telling you it's not a `Blob` or a `File`.

In this case it looks like `avatar` is an array.

```
this.setState({
    avatar: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file) // this is an array
});
```

So instead of using `avatar`, which is the entire array, you can select the first element in the array with `avatar[0]`

```
const upload = storage.ref(`avatars/${credential.user.uid}`).put(avatar[0])
```